# Scala Spark DataFrame Question:How to add new columns by matching the value in current row to somewhere from previous rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need help with Spark Dataframe.

The original dataframe df looks like this:

```
+---+---------+-------+---+------+
| id|      tim|  price|qty|qtyChg|
+---+---------+-------+---+------+
|  1|31951.509|  0.370|  1|     1|
|  2|31951.515|145.380|100|   100|
|  3|31951.519|149.370|100|   100|
|  4|31951.520|144.370|100|   100|
|  5|31951.520|149.370|300|   200|
|  6|31951.520|119.370|  5|     5|
|  7|31951.521|149.370|400|   100|
|  8|31951.522|109.370| 50|    50|
|  9|31951.522|149.370|410|    10|
| 10|31951.522|144.370|400|   300|
| 11|31951.522|149.870| 50|    50|
| 12|31951.524|149.370|610|   200|
| 13|31951.526|135.130| 22|    22|
| 14|31951.527|149.370|750|   140|
| 15|31951.528| 89.370|100|   100|
| 16|31951.528|145.870| 50|    50|
| 17|31951.528|139.370|100|   100|
| 18|31951.531|149.370|769|    19|
| 19|31951.531|144.370|410|    10|
| 20|31951.538|149.370|869|   100|
+---+---------+-------+---+------+
```

I am adding two columns `top1price` and `top2price`by code

```
val ww = Window.partitionBy().orderBy($"tim") 
val newdf = df.withColumn("sequence",sort_array(collect_set(col("price")).over(ww),asc=false))
                .withColumn("top1price",col("sequence").getItem(0))
                .withColumn("top2price",col("sequence").getItem(1)).drop("sequence")
```

newdf looks like this:

```
+---+---------+-------+---+------+---------+---------+
| id|      tim|  price|qty|qtyChg|top1price|top2price|
+---+---------+-------+---+------+---------+---------+
|  1|31951.509|  0.370|  1|     1|    0.370|     null|
|  2|31951.515|145.380|100|   100|  145.380|    0.370|
|  3|31951.519|149.370|100|   100|  149.370|  145.380|
|  4|31951.520|119.370|  5|     5|  149.370|  145.380|
|  5|31951.520|144.370|100|   100|  149.370|  145.380|
|  6|31951.520|149.370|300|   200|  149.370|  145.380|
|  7|31951.521|149.370|400|   100|  149.370|  145.380|
|  8|31951.522|109.370| 50|    50|  149.870|  149.370|
|  9|31951.522|144.370|400|   300|  149.870|  149.370|
| 10|31951.522|149.370|410|    10|  149.870|  149.370|
| 11|31951.522|149.870| 50|    50|  149.870|  149.370|
| 12|31951.524|149.370|610|   200|  149.870|  149.370|
| 13|31951.526|135.130| 22|    22|  149.870|  149.370|
| 14|31951.527|149.370|750|   140|  149.870|  149.370|
| 15|31951.528| 89.370|100|   100|  149.870|  149.370|
| 16|31951.528|139.370|100|   100|  149.870|  149.370|
| 17|31951.528|145.870| 50|    50|  149.870|  149.370|
| 18|31951.531|144.370|410|    10|  149.870|  149.370|
| 19|31951.531|149.370|769|    19|  149.870|  149.370|
| 20|31951.538|144.880|200|   200|  149.870|  149.370|
+---+---------+-------+---+------+---------+---------+
```

The logic behind top1price is what is the highest price so far at every moment. For example, at time 31951.520 (`id = 6`), the highest price by that time is 149.370 which comes from row `id=6`. The second-highest price by that time is 145.38 which comes from row2. I am interested in add two more columns `top1priceQty` and `top2priceQty`. The same example, in row 6, the highest price is 149.370 and its corresponding qty is 300 which also comes from row 6. The `top2price` is 145.380 and its `top2priceQty` would 100 which also comes from row2.

```
 |  8|31951.522|109.370| 50|    50|  149.870|  149.370|
```

For row8, `top1price` is 149.870 which comes from row 11 because row 8 to row 11 are the same moment. So by that time, 149.870 is the highest price and its corresponding `top1priceQty` would be 50. `top2price` is 149.370 which comes from row7, so is corresponding `top2priceQty` is 400 which also comes from row 7.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think lag and lead function can be useful

Comment: here you don't have any `partitionBy` column for the `window`. Please note that, using lag and lead without `partionBy` degrade the job performance seriously. for the big data of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting problem. I would like to mention a couple of points here.

1. Here we need to get the max and second max value for price column "so    far".
2. "so far" mean we need to use all the data till given point and partitioning is not required.
3. In order to specify the unbounded window specification for start of the window we will use "Window.unboundedPreceding".
4. We will use rowsBetween function to specify the window from beginnning to current row.

// Lets create a sample DataFrame

```
// Lets create a sample DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq((1, 31951.509, 0.370, 1, 1),
              (2, 31951.515, 145.380, 100,100),
              (3, 31951.519, 149.370, 100, 100),
              (4, 31951.520, 144.370, 100, 100),
              (5, 31951.520, 149.370, 300, 200),
              (6, 31951.520, 119.370, 5, 5))
        .toDF("id", "tim", "price", "qty", "qtyChg")
        .orderBy("id")

// Define the window specification which starts from beginning (specified by "Window.unboundedPreceding") and and end at current row (specified by value 0).
val winSpec = Window.orderBy("tim").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)

// Collect all the values and sort them in descending order.
val df1 = df.withColumn("sort_array", sort_array(collect_list(struct("price", "qty")).over(winSpec), asc=false))

// Fectch the elements at position 1 and 2 which represent the max and second max value.

val df2 = df1//.withColumn("top1price", element_at(sort_array(array_distinct($"sort_array.price"), asc=false), 1))
             //.withColumn("top2price", element_at(sort_array(array_distinct($"sort_array.price"), asc=false), 2))
             .withColumn("top1price", element_at(array_distinct($"sort_array.price"), 1))
             .withColumn("top2price", element_at(array_distinct($"sort_array.price"), 2))
             .withColumn("top1priceQty", element_at($"sort_array.qty", 1))
             .withColumn("top2priceQty", element_at($"sort_array.qty", 2))
             .drop("sort_array")

// Display the result.
df2.show(truncate= false)
```

> ```
>  // Output
> ```

```
+---+---------+------+---+------+---------+---------+------------+------------+
|id |tim      |price |qty|qtyChg|top1price|top2price|top1priceQty|top2priceQty|
+---+---------+------+---+------+---------+---------+------------+------------+
|1  |31951.509|0.37  |1  |1     |0.37     |null     |1           |null        |
|2  |31951.515|145.38|100|100   |145.38   |0.37     |100         |1           |
|3  |31951.519|149.37|100|100   |149.37   |145.38   |100         |100         |
|4  |31951.52 |144.37|100|100   |149.37   |145.38   |100         |100         |
|5  |31951.52 |149.37|300|200   |149.37   |145.38   |300         |100         |
|6  |31951.52 |119.37|5  |5     |149.37   |145.38   |300         |100         |
+---+---------+------+---+------+---------+---------+------------+------------+
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Neerja, do you know how to get the corresponding qty of  `top1price` and `top2price`
?

Comment: I have updated the code to add the corresponding qty as well. Let me know if this looks ok to you.

Comment: Hi Neerja, I am not expecting top1price is the same as top2price.They should be different. at `id=5`, `top1price` is 149.37 and its qty is 300,but `top2price` would be 145.38 and its qty is 100.

Comment: Hi, @QuencyYu I have updated the code slightly. Let me know if you still have any issue.

Comment: Hi Neerja, yes, top1price and top2price are correct now. But their corresponding qty of top2price is not correctly matched. One more problem is in id=6, the top1price and top2price don't look right. I solved the issue by setting `val winSpec = Window.orderBy("tim")` The only problem here is how to return the top2priceQty correctly

Comment: Between Its "Neeraj" here. In `top2priceQty` what value you are expecting? Here, the `top2priceQty` is corresponding to `top2price`. is that not you are expecting? Regarding the ordering of ID, you can remove the ordering based on "tim" column in my code if that is not expected. Could you please share an example what `top2priceQty` you are expecting.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! Hi Neeraj! Using your example, in `id=2`, `top1price`= 145.38 and `top1priceQty` is 100. It is right. But `top2price` should be 0.37 and its `top2priceQty` would be 1 because we are ordering by time. In id=4, `top1price` should be 149.37 and `top1priceQty` is 300 which comes from row id=3. `top2price` should be 145.38  and its `top2priceQty` is 100 which comes from row id=2. In id=5, the  `top2priceQty` value looks right, but it's actually from the qty in row id =3 instead of row id=2 according to your code. If you change the qty in row id=3, you will see what I mean.

Comment: I have again updated the code slightly. You have mentioned for id=4, `top1priceQty` is 300 which comes from id=3. however, for id=2, qty is 100, which looks good in my output. please check and confirm.

Comment: Hi Neeraj, the problem id=4 is solved.Thanks! I want to emphasize id=3 issue.  If you change the qty value in row id=3 to 6, then you run your code again, you will find in row id= 6, top2priceQty will return 6 but I am expecting its value still 100. Could you try to modify the qty value?You will understand my issue then

Comment: Hi Quency, How we can expect the qty in id=3 to 6 when id=3 event happened earlier than id=6. And we are taking the records to calculate the top price and corresponding quantity we have so far (at a given point of time). So while processing id=3, we don't have records corresponding to id=6 to consider for processing. For all the `top1price` and `top2price` we are getting the max and second max price at a given point and getting the corresponding quantity in above output in `top1priceQty` and `top2priceQty`.

Comment: Hi Neeraj, while processing id=6, we will have a max price of 149.37 and the second max price is 145.38. Then having max price information, we are matching the corresponding qty. If you change the quantity to 6 in id=3,  then the top2priceQty will become 6 because of the code  `element_at($"sort_array.qty", 2)`. However, the top2price is 145.38  and its qty is 100 which comes from row id=2. Can you understand my concern?

Comment: Hi Neeraj, thank you for your help!!! I finally solved the issue. the code I am using to get top2priceQty is              `.withColumn("top2priceQty", element_at($"sort_array.qty",array_position($"sort_array.price",$"top2price").cast("int")))`

Comment: I am glad that you managed to solve the issue. feel free to accept and upvote the answer if you feel it was useful.

Comment: Hi Neeraj, I accepted your answer. Unfortunately, StackOverflow doesn't allow me to upvote. but I definitely upvote your answer! Thanks！

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve this using following approach.

Please note that:

- I haven't performed any performance testing, hence use this after performing some performance experiments using some variation of data as per the requirement. The below solution will affect the performance badly since there is no `partitionBy` clause in the `windowing`
- Please check the output, and see whether its satisfies your requirement or not. I haven't done row by row match. But I think it should work.

### Code (self-explanatory)

1. Load the data

```
val data =
      """
        |id|      tim|  price|qty|qtyChg
        | 1|31951.509|  0.370|  1|     1
        | 2|31951.515|145.380|100|   100
        | 3|31951.519|149.370|100|   100
        | 4|31951.520|144.370|100|   100
        | 5|31951.520|149.370|300|   200
        | 6|31951.520|119.370|  5|     5
        | 7|31951.521|149.370|400|   100
        | 8|31951.522|109.370| 50|    50
        | 9|31951.522|149.370|410|    10
        |10|31951.522|144.370|400|   300
        |11|31951.522|149.870| 50|    50
        |12|31951.524|149.370|610|   200
        |13|31951.526|135.130| 22|    22
        |14|31951.527|149.370|750|   140
        |15|31951.528| 89.370|100|   100
        |16|31951.528|145.870| 50|    50
        |17|31951.528|139.370|100|   100
        |18|31951.531|149.370|769|    19
        |19|31951.531|144.370|410|    10
        |20|31951.538|149.370|869|   100
      """.stripMargin

    val stringDS = data.split(System.lineSeparator())
      .map(_.split("\\|").map(_.replaceAll("""^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$""", "")).mkString(","))
      .toSeq.toDS()
    val df = spark.read
      .option("sep", ",")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("header", "true")
      .csv(stringDS)
    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()
```

Output-

```
+---+---------+------+---+------+
|id |tim      |price |qty|qtyChg|
+---+---------+------+---+------+
|1  |31951.509|0.37  |1  |1     |
|2  |31951.515|145.38|100|100   |
|3  |31951.519|149.37|100|100   |
|4  |31951.52 |144.37|100|100   |
|5  |31951.52 |149.37|300|200   |
|6  |31951.52 |119.37|5  |5     |
|7  |31951.521|149.37|400|100   |
|8  |31951.522|109.37|50 |50    |
|9  |31951.522|149.37|410|10    |
|10 |31951.522|144.37|400|300   |
|11 |31951.522|149.87|50 |50    |
|12 |31951.524|149.37|610|200   |
|13 |31951.526|135.13|22 |22    |
|14 |31951.527|149.37|750|140   |
|15 |31951.528|89.37 |100|100   |
|16 |31951.528|145.87|50 |50    |
|17 |31951.528|139.37|100|100   |
|18 |31951.531|149.37|769|19    |
|19 |31951.531|144.37|410|10    |
|20 |31951.538|149.37|869|100   |
+---+---------+------+---+------+

root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- tim: double (nullable = true)
 |-- price: double (nullable = true)
 |-- qty: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- qtyChg: integer (nullable = true)
```

2. Fetch the highest and second highest price and related quantity

```scala
   val w = Window.orderBy("tim").rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
    val w1 = Window.orderBy("tim")

    val processedDF = df.withColumn("maxPriceQty", max(struct(col("price"), col("qty"))).over(w))
      .withColumn("secondMaxPriceQty", lag(col("maxPriceQty"), 1).over(w1))
      .withColumn("top1price", col("maxPriceQty.price"))
      .withColumn("top1priceQty", col("maxPriceQty.qty"))
      .withColumn("top2price", col("secondMaxPriceQty.price"))
      .withColumn("top2priceQty", col("secondMaxPriceQty.qty"))
      processedDF.show(false)
```

Output-

```
+---+---------+------+---+------+-------------+-----------------+---------+------------+---------+------------+
|id |tim      |price |qty|qtyChg|maxPriceQty  |secondMaxPriceQty|top1price|top1priceQty|top2price|top2priceQty|
+---+---------+------+---+------+-------------+-----------------+---------+------------+---------+------------+
|1  |31951.509|0.37  |1  |1     |[0.37, 1]    |null             |0.37     |1           |null     |null        |
|2  |31951.515|145.38|100|100   |[145.38, 100]|[0.37, 1]        |145.38   |100         |0.37     |1           |
|3  |31951.519|149.37|100|100   |[149.37, 100]|[145.38, 100]    |149.37   |100         |145.38   |100         |
|4  |31951.52 |144.37|100|100   |[149.37, 300]|[149.37, 100]    |149.37   |300         |149.37   |100         |
|5  |31951.52 |149.37|300|200   |[149.37, 300]|[149.37, 300]    |149.37   |300         |149.37   |300         |
|6  |31951.52 |119.37|5  |5     |[149.37, 300]|[149.37, 300]    |149.37   |300         |149.37   |300         |
|7  |31951.521|149.37|400|100   |[149.37, 400]|[149.37, 300]    |149.37   |400         |149.37   |300         |
|8  |31951.522|109.37|50 |50    |[149.87, 50] |[149.37, 400]    |149.87   |50          |149.37   |400         |
|9  |31951.522|149.37|410|10    |[149.87, 50] |[149.87, 50]     |149.87   |50          |149.87   |50          |
|10 |31951.522|144.37|400|300   |[149.87, 50] |[149.87, 50]     |149.87   |50          |149.87   |50          |
|11 |31951.522|149.87|50 |50    |[149.87, 50] |[149.87, 50]     |149.87   |50          |149.87   |50          |
|12 |31951.524|149.37|610|200   |[149.87, 50] |[149.87, 50]     |149.87   |50          |149.87   |50          |
|13 |31951.526|135.13|22 |22    |[149.87, 50] |[149.87, 50]     |149.87   |50          |149.87   |50          |
|14 |31951.527|149.37|750|140   |[149.87, 50] |[149.87, 50]     |149.87   |50          |149.87   |50          |
|15 |31951.528|89.37 |100|100   |[149.87, 50] |[149.87, 50]     |149.87   |50          |149.87   |50          |
|16 |31951.528|145.87|50 |50    |[149.87, 50] |[149.87, 50]     |149.87   |50          |149.87   |50          |
|17 |31951.528|139.37|100|100   |[149.87, 50] |[149.87, 50]     |149.87   |50          |149.87   |50          |
|18 |31951.531|149.37|769|19    |[149.87, 50] |[149.87, 50]     |149.87   |50          |149.87   |50          |
|19 |31951.531|144.37|410|10    |[149.87, 50] |[149.87, 50]     |149.87   |50          |149.87   |50          |
|20 |31951.538|149.37|869|100   |[149.87, 50] |[149.87, 50]     |149.87   |50          |149.87   |50          |
+---+---------+------+---+------+-------------+-----------------+---------+------------+---------+------------+
```

> Please observe last 4 output columns and for explanation of rowsBetween and rangeBetween follow [this](https://www.sqlpassion.at/archive/2015/01/22/sql-server-windowing-functions-rows-vs-range/) link

Comment: Hi Kale, thank you for the help! I have one concern with the output. At `id=6`, I am expecting `top2price` should be 144.37. 149.37 occur twice, I am only using the newest one value. `top2price` would be different from `top1price`. Do you know how to solve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: at `id=15`, I am expecting `top1price` should be 149.87 instead of 145.87

Comment: Hi Kale, I changed the code a little bit.For the maxPrice qty, I use : `val w = Window.partitionBy().orderBy("tim")`,  `df.withColumn("maxPriceQty", max(struct(col("price"), col("qty"))).over(w))`

Comment: Hi Kale, top2price can not be the same as top1price.Do you know how to modify your code to get the result? And the corresponding priceqty?

Comment: Hi @QuencyYu, updated the answer, please check now, I think it should work

Comment: Hi Kale, thank you for the help! Problem is solved!

Comment: @QuencyYu can you accept + upvote this? help- https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers